# Installing RSpec in Rubygem

Tags: rubygems, rspec2

I have decided to create my first gem and now I'm trying to install RSpec.

I have added `spec.add_development_dependency "rspec", "~> 2.14"` to my .gemspec file and I have created spec/spec_helper.rb as below

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:default, :development)

require 'my_gem' 


RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.color_enabled = true
  config.formatter     = 'documentation'

  config.order = 'random'
end
```

After bundle it up, I have finally added spec/foobar_spec.rb as below

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'foobar' do
  expect(1).to eq(2)
end
```

But when I run rspec spec/foobar_spec.rb I get

**undefined method `expect' for # (NoMethodError)**

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Rspec docs](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations#basic-usage), expectations must be defined within `it` blocks:

```
describe 'foobar' do
   it { expect(1).to eq(2) }
end
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Not sure why I overlooked at it.

Comment: If this answer resolved your issue, would you kindly consider accepting it as correct?

Comment: I have to wait for 2 more minutes ;)